# What controls the coordinate value in the singleclick MapBrowserEvent argument?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, events

I am trying to understand what is affecting the "singleclick" callback argument: MapBrowserEvent in my OpenLayers map (v6.4.3).

While I always receive the pixel coordinates back, I don't always get a coordinate back on the MapBrowserEvent object.

Here's one where the coordinate was returned:
[image]

And one where I do not get a coordinate back:
[image]

Once I receive an event with empty an coordinate, all subsequent events have an empty coordinate.  But no errors in the console.

I am wiring up events like this:

```
this.map.on("singleclick", function (evt) {
  console.log(`MapComponent.setupMap - Map - click - evt=`, evt);
  component.onMapClick(evt);
});


this.map.on("dblclick", function (evt) {
  console.log(`MapComponent.setupMap - Map - dblclick - evt=`, evt);
  component.onMapDoubleClick(evt);
});
```

I want to understand this behavior, before implementing a workaround (***which I assume is just going to be converting the pixel coords to lat/lon***).

Comment: Not able to reproduce e.g always got coordinate https://codesandbox.io/s/popup-forked-0svj6 Same OpenLayers version 6.4.1

Comment: But there must be some difference what's under the cursor when event gives coordinates and when there are no coordinates?

Comment: Circling back to this.  Yes, there was something different that I missed.  Once I interacted with a control, then my coordinate returned empty.  If I don't interact with controls and simply click the map, it works.